# Draw a polygon from the mentioned data

Tags: coordinate-system, polygon, geojson

I want to draw a polygon from the below JSON data from a GeoJSON file. However I am confused about the coordinates array since I believed they corresponded to a latitude and a longitude. But clearly from the below example they are not valid longitude and latitudes.

```
{
"type": "Feature",
"geometry": {
    "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": [
        [
            [7634622.475699998, 1247905.0877999999],
            [7634603.934699997, 1247985.6240000017],
            [7634671.5713, 1248001.2551000006],
            [7634660.179200001, 1247921.3847999983],
            [7634622.475699998, 1247905.0877999999]
        ]
    ]
},
"properties": {
    "OBJECTID": 1,
    "Longitude": -73.520563459,
    "Latitude": 45.522783335,
    "CSDUID": "2458227",
    "CSDNAME": "Longueuil",
    "Data_prov": "Longueuil",
    "Build_ID": "24582270000001",
    "Shape_Leng": 301.838065514,
    "Shape_Area": 4277.81119671
}
```

}

The below JSON from GeoJSON renders as a polygon since the coordinates point to a longitude and latitude. Do I need to parse the above JSON differently?

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [{
    "type": "Feature",
    "id": "osm-r554096",
    "properties": {},
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
            [
                [2.359211, 48.850304],
                [2.359124, 48.850431],
                [2.359173, 48.850497],
                [2.359228, 48.850565],
                [2.359262, 48.850612],
                [2.359184, 48.850637],
                [2.359174, 48.850628],
                [2.359107, 48.85065],
                [2.359087, 48.850657],
                [2.35893, 48.85071],
                [2.358843, 48.850597],
                [2.358682, 48.850385],
                [2.358608, 48.850288],
                [2.358733, 48.850247],
                [2.358837, 48.850213],
                [2.358871, 48.850213],
                [2.35891, 48.850213],
                [2.359022, 48.850247],
                [2.359211, 48.850304]
            ]
        ]
    }
}]
```

}

Comment: The first geometry is a polygon but in some other coordinate reference system than WGS84 longitude-latitude. Ask the data provider what is the CRS that they use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find an unknown projection using `projfinder.com` if you have a coordinate in lat-long and a nearby coordinate in the other system.

From your data, I took one of the points in the geoJSON:

```
 7634671.5713, 1248001.2551000006
```

and zoomed into this coordinate from the geoJSON attribute data:

```
"Longitude": -73.520563459,
"Latitude": 45.522783335,
```

`projfinder` tells me that either of these two coordinate systems:

```
0   EPSG:3347 Name:NAD83 / Statistics Canada Lambert    Distance:254.143075
1   EPSG:3348 Name:NAD83(CSRS) / Statistics Canada Lambert  Distance:254.143075
```

maps to lat-long:

```
 -73.519263 , 45.525259
```

which is pretty close. I guess your points are in EPSG:3347 coordinates. How you convert them to lat-long is dependent on the software you are using.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In case I need to change my CRS then do you know which one can match the one which has Latitude and Longitude?

Comment: As I said (sorry if I wasn't clear) but I used http://projfinder.com/ - put an X-Y projected coordinate in the boxes, zoom to the lat-long where you think it is, and it finds the nearest projections. If there's a point not too far, then that's probably it.

Comment: By definition, GeoJSON is SRID 4326 (GCS WGS84).

Comment: @Vince RFC 7946 says "However, where all involved parties have a prior arrangement, alternative coordinate reference systems can be used without risk of data being misinterpreted.". I suspect such prior arrangement has not been made here...

Comment: Thanks guys this worked.